# Write an output of a loop into a dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I wrote this scala code to do something for each row in a Spark DataFrame. Basically these are the steps I do

```
1. I convert the DataFrame into an array 
2. Iterate through the array and perform calculations and get the output in an array
3. convert the output of the array to a dataframe and then make a Hive table.
```

It is in step 2 i have issues when i run for a million records. Is there anyway I can enhance the performance. FYI I only convert a dataframe to an array because AFAIK spark dataframe cannot be iterated.

```
def getRows (ca : org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame ) = 
{
  val allca = List()
  for (a <- ca.collect()) yield
  {
    val newAddress = a.getString(1)
    val output = newAddress  :: getRecursiveList(newAddress).reverse


  val dataset = 
 CA (account.getInt(0),
            account.getString(1),
            account.getString(2), 
            output.toString)

  dataset :: allca
  }
}

val myArray = getRows(customerAccounts)

val OutputDataFrame = sc.parallelize(myArray.flatMap(x => x)).toDF

OutputDataFrame.show()


val resultsRDD = OutputDataFrame.registerTempTable("history")

spark.sql(""" insert into user_tech.history select * from history """).collect.foreach(println)
```

Comment: can't you just write an UDF?

Comment: Good point, I can do that. I just wanted to know if this is possible

Comment: see also spark inbuilt functions https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.2/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html if you can use them. They should give you better performance than udf. But if your logic cannot be done through one of the functions, then you have to go with udf function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please understand some basics:

1. Spark scala/Java API provide a very high level perspective and do not provide any idea of distributed nature of the  data structure.
2. Iterating over a data-frames has two option : are you iterating over them in a distributed way or collecting all the data on a single machine and then iterating.
3. ca.collect() is collecting data from data-frame from all the nodes and getting the data to driver to process which is not a scalable solution.

   Please follow following links for better understanding

   1. http://bytepadding.com/big-data/spark/spark-code-analysis/
   2. http://bytepadding.com/big-data/spark/understanding-spark-through-map-reduce/